# How to read the <Static Call Graph> generated by ARM Linker?

Tags: c, debugging, compiler-construction, arm, stm32

I'm a little confused about the Stack Size, Thumb and Max Depth shown on the  file. Which is generated by the ARM Linker.

**1. Where could I found the information what these several words exactly meaning?**

for example:

```
f_open (Thumb, 450 bytes, Stack size 608 bytes, ff.o(i.f_open)) 

[Stack]
Max Depth = 840
Call Chain = f_open ⇒ dir_register ⇒ dir_find ⇒ dir_next ⇒ create_chain ⇒ put_fat ⇒ move_window ⇒ sync_window ⇒ disk_write

[Calls]
>>   get_fattime
>>   st_clust
>>   remove_chain
>>   move_window
>>   ld_clust
>>   inc_lock
>>   follow_path
>>   find_volume
>>   enq_lock
>>   dir_register
>>   chk_lock
```

I know the Max Depth is the Stack needed of the Longest Call Chain. Is that means, for this function, the stack it needed is exactly equal the Max Depth?

If so, what about the 'Stack Size'? Is which means the stack size of the current function itself needed?

If so, what's the 'Thumb'? Is which means that, 'Thumb' Instruction Set?

Could I say:
 `Max Depth=Thumb + all Stack Size in the call chain + some other unknown exception`?

**2. How to read the Call Graph file?** 
I've noticed that there are several piece in the file

z. Maximum Stack Usage = xxxx bytes + Unknown(Cycles, Untraceable Function Pointers)
a. Call chain for Maximum Stack Depth
b. Mutually Recursive functions
c. Function Pointers
d. Global Symbols
e. Local Symbols
f. Undefined Global Symbols

Is the 'Local Symbols' response to the functions which aren't referenced on the .h header file?

**3. Why the call chain doesn't show the Heap Size of the function?**

**4. Could the Maximum Stack Usage indicate the real Max Stack Needed?**

For example, one of my project, it shows     `Maximum Stack Usage = 78160 bytes + Unknown(Cycles, Untraceable Function Pointers)`in the Static Call Graph file.

But the stack size I setted in the startup file is 0xDFA0 (57248 bytes, I found this value by experiment), in this size of stack, my program works well in most time, and in some case it doesn't work well. Why it could still work well?

**5. Where could I get the knowledge about my question upper?**

for these several questions, I've found answer on internet for about one whole but finally get nothing. Where and how could I learn about those knowledge?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Books, documentation. Or by googling and asking here.
   I can't find very detailed documentation of [the callgraph](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0493f/CHDGDFFF.html) in the infocenter right now, but I think:

   > f_open (Thumb, 450 bytes, Stack size 608 bytes, ff.o(i.f_open))

   - `Thumb` is the instruction set mode.
   - `450 bytes` is the function size.
   - `608 bytes` is the predicable stack depth. **It can't follow interrupts!**
   - `ff.o(i.f_open)` is the object the linker put it in.
2. It gives you a report of information that you can analyze.
   z. The maximum predictable stack usage.
   a. It shows you where the most functions are called.
   b. It shows [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) functions. These can be dangerous.
   c. It lists all functions and symbols.
   e. Local symbols are non-global symbols. Basically with `static`.
   f. I don't know what undefined global symbols are. My projects seem to have none.
3. Heap is runtime use of malloc. This is not predictable because the size of the malloc can be defined on other runtime values. Do you use heap?
4. That is **a lot** of stack. This is the predictable use of stack. Based on function calls and automatic variables. It does not take interrupts into account. So you'd need to manually calculate the worst case interrupt path, if you have one stack. (Cortex M4 uses two stacks)
   That would be: Maximum stack + all allowed interrupts during that time + fault handler.
5. The ARM Infocenter offers documentation on the core and toolchain.
   Depending on your education, you might also have seen these subject being taught.